# Could Eye of Gruumsh be safely interpreted as Racial Subsitution Levels?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature, prestige-class, barbarian, orc

I am sure most can agree the Eye of Gruumsh prestige class is very dated and extremely sub-par compared to what has come out afterward.

Would incorporating the prestige class into the barbarian core class as racial substitution levels be a safe alternative; in relation to power level, scalability, and class balance? How would this compare to the standard barbarian?

So, "what three class features should be substituted to make eye of gruumsh into a orc barbarian substitution class" (thank you BrianBallsun-Stanton).

I have provided an examplea of what I am speaking of below:

> **ORC BARBARIAN**
>
> Orcs, typically savage, ill-tempered, violent, and dangerous produce many barbarians within their societies. Some of those Orcs remove one of their eyes in reverence of their deity, Gruumsh. Those that survive this traumatizing ritual gain insight that other orcs do not possess.
>
> **Hit Die:** d12
>
> **Requirements:** To take orc barbarian substitution levels, a character must be an orc or half-orc, worship Gruumsh as a patron deity, and be of Chaotic Neutral, Neutral Evil, or Chaotic Evil alignment.
>
> **Class Skills:** Orc barbarian substitution levels have the class skills of the standard barbarian class.
>
> **Skill Points at Each Level:** 4 + Int modifier (or four times this number as a beginning character).
>
> **Class Features:** All the following are class features of orc barbarian racial substitution levels.
>
> **1st Level**
>
> **Blind Fighting (Ex):** An orc barbarian gains Blind-Fight as a bonus feat. In addition, he suffers no adverse effects from the loss of one of his eyes.
>   This racial substitution level replaces the standard barbarian’s Fast Movement ability.
>
> **Blind Rage (Ex):** An orc barbarian can fly into a rage a certain number of times per day. In a rage, an orc barbarian temporarily gains a +6 bonus to Strength, a +4 bonus to Constitution, and a +2 morale bonus on Will saves, but he takes a -3 penalty to Armor Class. The increase in Constitution increases the orc barbarian’s hit points by 2 points per level, but these hit points go away at the end of the rage when his Constitution score drops back to normal. (These extra hit points are not lost first the way temporary hit points are.)
>
> You also gain Improved Blind Rage and Superior Blind Rage, rather than Greater Rage and Mighty Rage (see below)
>
> This ability counts as Rage for all purposes and effects. This racial substitution level replaces the standard barbarian’s Rage ability.
>
> **2nd Level**
>
> **Blind Vision (Ex):** At 2nd level, an orc barbarian gains Blindsight (see page 306 of the Monster Manual) out to 5 feet. The range increases to 10 feet at 5th level.
>   This racial substitution level replaces the standard barbarian’s Uncanny Dodge and Improved Uncanny Dodge abilities.
>
> **3rd Level**
>
> **Inspire Orcs (Ex):** An orc barbarian can bolster the actions of any non-good orcs or half-orcs that are within 30 feet of him and whose Hit Dice are lower than his character level. Those who follow the character's orders gain a +1 morale bonus on Will saves. Any eligible orc or half-orc that willingly goes against the orc barbarian's directions loses this bonus immediately. This bonus raises by +1 every three orc barbarian levels thereafter.
>
> This racial substitution level replaces the standard barbarian’s Trap Sense ability.
>
> **7th level**
>
> **Thick Skin (Ex):** Through frequent scarification of his own skin, an orc barbarian's natural armor bonus improves by +2 at 7th level (or to +2 if he didn't already have a natural armor bonus). This bonus increases by another +1 for every three levels gained thereafter.
>
> This racial substitution level replaces the standard barbarian’s Damage Reduction ability.
>
> **11th Level**
>
> **Improved Blind Rage (Ex):** At 11th level, during his rage, an orc barbarian’s bonus to Strength increases to +8, his bonus to Constitution increases +6, and his morale bonus on Will saves increases to +3. The penalty to AC increases to -4.
>   This counts as Greater Rage for all purposes and effects. This racial substitution level replaces the standard barbarian’s Greater Rage ability.
>
> **14th Level**
>
> **Foreknowledge (Ex):** At 14th level, an orc barbarian gains the ability to see the moment of his own death through his missing eye. This foreknowledge gives him a +2 morale bonus on all saving throws and Armor Class from then on. He also gains the benefit of the Diehard feat. (Whether or not the vision is accurate is irrelevant—the character believes it to be true.)
>
> This racial substitution level replaces the standard barbarian’s Indomitable Will ability.
>
> **20th Level**
>
> **Superior Blind Rage (Ex):** At 20th level, during his rage, an orc barbarian’s bonuses to Strength increases to +12, his bonus to Constitution increases to +8, and his morale bonus on Will saves increases to +4. The penalty to AC remains at -4.
>   This ability counts as Mighty Rage for all purposes and effects.
>
> This racial substitution level replaces the standard barbarian’s Mighty Rage ability.

Comment: So, "what three class features should be substituted to make eye of gruumsh into a orc barbarian substitution class" seems to be your question. ... Everything else here seems to be a potential ... answer to that question.

Comment: I feel that the three different types of rage, should really be only one ability that just scales at the appropriate levels.

Comment: How is this not just asking the site to homebrew this for you? I see no requirements or goals for suggestions that would make answers anything other than personal opinion on what to do with this.